# Unable to send authorisation token or some data in headers in axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, mern, request-headers

I am sending this from my react frontend to my node backend

```
const data = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/login', {email, password}, { 
          headers:{ 
            'Authorization':'somesecretkey'
          }
        });
```

Where I am trying to accept headers like this

```
 const { headers } = req;
    console.log(headers);
```

but i am getting this

```
{
    host: 'localhost:5000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '54',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.59',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
  }
```

*that is i am not getting any Authorisation header in backend.*

**What i am doing wrong?**

Comment: Could you try to put in another header... like `X-custom1: test` or something.  Then we will know if somebody is intercepting that special header, or there is a problem with headers in general

Comment: maybe just modify your question to have two headers in the request, and show that response

Comment: Also could you please try to post to your server using `curl`? Then we will know if the problem is on the express(?) or axios side of things `curl -X POST  -H "Authorization: TEST" -H 'X-Custom-Test: TEST' -d '{"user": "UG", "password": "test123"}' http://localhost:5000/api/login` I think

Comment: After I posted this question I tried changing my cors in backend with 'Access-control-allow-headers':'\*' , then it begin to show that same header in backend, but now I didn't understand what is happening even if I again remove cors 'Access-control-allow-headers':'\*'  then also I am getting any header that I am sending from frontend now I am confused why it is working when previously it was not working previously I also tried changing costom header names but no success , and now suddenly everything is working fine just with the same code that I posted above

Comment: Do anybody have any idea that what could he the reason, that it was not working earlier and now suddenly everything is working great? Before I posted this question I tried so many times but no success was there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it still needs to be answered. But, are you sure this is the right way to do it?
For example, I do it the following way and never had this issue

```
await axios ({
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/login',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
       Authorization: 'somesecretkey',
    }
});
```

Corresponding to the type definition of AxiosRequestConfig

```
AxiosRequestConfig<D = any> {
  url?: string;
  method?: Method;
  baseURL?: string;
  headers?: AxiosRequestHeaders;
  params?: any;
  data?: D;
}
```

let me know if it works?
Cheers